# How to verify the input data in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to verify if I am feeding the correct data to the TensorFlow graph. I am using `tf.FixedLengthRecordReader()` to read the data and populate the queue.

I am not very clear what is the right way to make sure I am reading the correct data. Because, when I am creating my queue/graph - input queue is still empty.

Where can I create a `tf.InteractiveSession()` and try a `sess.run(input_image)` to print the actual input and label?

Additionally, I have even tried the latest Tensorflow Debugger `tfdbg` and I don't see any logged tensor for inputs.

Comment: FYI. The recommended (and universally l loved) way of reading data is using the Dataset API - https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets. You might want to try it instead. Otherwise, can you post relevant code to clearly illustrate your approach and issue. Without additional info, I am not sure why something like `print session.run(reader.read())` does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

With `tfdbg`, you can find and inspect the feed dict under 'run_info'.

[image]

Voila!
[image]